# Как отправить из формы только те поля, где выставлен чекбокс?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, checkbox, форма

Доброго времени суток!

Не понимаю как сделать.

Есть форма, в ней куча полей. Мне нужно сохранить только те поля, у которых отмечен чекбокс.

Проблема в том, что не умею собирать массивы с js.

Набросал обработчик формы, но как выцепить нужные поля не знаю

```
$(function() {
    $('.ajax_save').click(function(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "a.php?action=checkAttr",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function()
            {
                $('.ok').css('display','block');
            },
            error: function()
            {
                $('.error').css('display','block');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Сам чекбокс такой в цикле

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkId['.$id.']" value="1" />
```

Поля с этим же id такие

```
<input type="text" name="' . $id . '_sort" value="' . $sort . '">
```

т.е. поля **ID_название**

Каким образом можно выцепить выделенные чекбоксы, взять из них ID и собрать новый массив из нужных полей формы с этим же ID, чтобы отправить только нужные данные?

Переделывать саму форму или вывод в ней не вариант. делали давно, кода очень много, я пока еще не разобрался вообще в нем полностью. По этому хочу просто обойти.

Буду благодарен за помощь и ответы!

Comment: Получилось написать обработку. Вопрос можно закрыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение моей задачи.

js

```
$(function(){
    $('.ajax_save_form').on('click', function() {

        var values = {},
            fields = {};

        // получаем все чекбоксы (нужно указать еще форму. а то соберет все чекбоксы страницы)
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
            // выбранные чекбоксы
            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                // вытаскиваем ID чекбокса(может не правильно, но работает)
                id = $(this).attr("name").match(/\[(\d+)\]\s?(.*)/);

                // поля у которых выбран чекбокс с id
                var values = {
                    field1: $('input[name="'+id[1]+'_field1"]').val(),
                    field2: $('input[name="'+id[1]+'_field2"]').val()
                };

                fields[id[1]] = values;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_url.php?action=save_form",
            type: "post",
            data: {fields: fields},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                // ok
            },
            error: function(data) {
                // error
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    // поля с ID 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="1_field1" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="1_field2" value="0" />
    // поля с ID 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[2]" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="2_field1" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="2_field2" value="0" />

    <input type="submit" class="ajax_save_form" value="Сохранить" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text_inpt=new Array;
var i=0;
$("input[type:'text']").each(
    var tmp=$(this).attr("name").split("_");
    text_inpt[i++]=tmp[0];
);
```

оправляем массив text_inpt на сервер и массив выделенных чекбоксов. На стороне сервера извлекаем из text_inpt те элементы, ключи которых совападают с ключами отправленных чекбокосов.

Comment: Спасибо.
Либо я не понял, либо не так. на стороне сервера нужно получать уже готовую инфу, так как не отправляется вся форма с таким количеством полей, которые есть. Раньше полей было не много и проблем не было. Сейчас полей огромное количество и форма вся не уходит. По этому и решил, что отправлять нужно только выбранные данные, а не все скопом.

Comment: Так Вы на сервер отправляете только массив, а не форму.

Если форма не вся уходит, попробуйте метод изменить на POST, если у вас стоит GET.

Comment: Пост и отправляет. Я просто собираю все чекбоксы, выбрал те, которые отмечены, получил нужный ID этих чекбоксов и собираю массив полей исходя из ID.